# How do I scale down integers from multiple values in a dictionary (dividing multiple times)?

Tags: python

Using this code to scale down these categories by a million. Works okay the first time I run it, but if I run it again it is divides by a million again. How do I fix this?

```
def scale_down_movie(movie):
    selected_keys = ('budget', 'budget_2013$', 'domgross', 'domgross_2013$', 'intgross', 'intgross_2013$')
    for key in selected_keys: 
        movie[key] = round(movie[key]/1000000,2)   
    return movie
```

Expected:

```
{'year': 2013,
 'imdb': 'tt1711425',
 'title': '21 &amp; Over',
 'test': 'notalk',
 'clean_test': 'notalk',
 'binary': 'FAIL',
 'budget': 13.0,
 'domgross': 25.68,
 'intgross': 42.2,
 'code': '2013FAIL',
 'budget_2013$': 13.0,
 'domgross_2013$': 25.68,
 'intgross_2013$': 42.2,
 'period code': 1.0,
 'decade code': 1.0}
```

Actual (2nd run and after):

```
{'year': 2013,
 'imdb': 'tt1711425',
 'title': '21 &amp; Over',
 'test': 'notalk',
 'clean_test': 'notalk',
 'binary': 'FAIL',
 'budget': 0.0,
 'domgross': 0.0,
 'intgross': 0.0,
 'code': '2013FAIL',
 'budget_2013$': 0.0,
 'domgross_2013$': 0.0,
 'intgross_2013$': 0.0,
 'period code': 1.0,
 'decade code': 1.0}
```

Comment: …is "don't run it again" an option?

Comment: Do the rounding on demand. For example, when printing.

Comment: Save the initial value of the floats. Have a check in the function that is something like: `if initial_values == current_values: #continue with function else return` ?

Comment: You're updating the values in your dictionary, so obviously if you run it again, it'll divide again on the _new_ values. Why would you want to run the function more than once?

Comment: @MarkMeyer no unfortunately not.

Comment: @JuanC I need to run it again because I am using it in later functions.

Comment: Do the round once and save it. Then use the rounded values later

Comment: @Valentino what do you think would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionaries are mutable in python.

So when you pass a dictionary to a function and the function modify it, you are modifying the original object, since python always pass by reference.

You can even remove the return statement from your function. Just call it once, and your original dictionary is modified (values are rounded).

---

However, if you wish to keep the original dictionary too, modify the function in this way:

```
def scale_down_movie(movie):
    selected_keys = ('budget',)
    res = {} #an empty dictionary
    for key in movie.keys():
        if key in selected_keys:
            res[key] = round(movie[key]/1000000,2)
        else:
            res[key] = movie[key]
    return res
```

As you see this function is creating a new dictionary and returning it instead of modifying the original.

If you do:

```
scaled_movie_dict = scale_down_movie(original_movie_dict)
```

`scaled_movie_dict` is you scaled dictionary which you can use whenever you want later.